# Kendo UI + AngularJS + treeview + context menu

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I have the following Kendo UI AngularJS tree that has a related context menu. How can I get the tree node that is selected when the context menu is opened on right click? The tree `k-on-change` event seems to be triggered only on left click.

[This is the plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/kWaQevKFKQhCD7ouurpV?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same Problem and fixed it by selecting the node by hand on right click.

Using ng-right-click you can assign selectedItem. Check your updated plunk below.

```
$scope.onRightClick = function(e) {
  var node = e.target;
  $scope.tree.select(node);
  $scope.selectedItem = $scope.tree.dataItem(node);
}
```

[Your fixed Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/hF1Xiyrz4kBH9kr5da5K?p=preview)